# jQuery load() return json value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, load

I have a page where I use jQuery load() method to display a table of results based on a post request of some fields. But I need this load() to display the table and also inform javascript if a condition is met in the PHP script, so probably I need a json response. I don't know if it's possible to use the complete() callback to achieve that. I only need a single variable to pass from my PHP script to javascript.

I'm using load() because I believe other ajax methods need to do the HTML template part from javascript, am I right?

Hope I made myself clear, thanks

**UPDATE1:**

Here is my js code:

```
$("#listaNegraView").load('procesos/funcionesAjax.php', 
            {accion: 'listaNegra', 
            nombres: $("#nombres").val(), 
            apellidoP: $("#apellidoP").val(),
            apellidoM: $("#apellidoM").val(),
            nacimiento: $("#nacimiento").val()},
            function(data){console.log(data);}
            );
```

And here is PHP script:

```
case 'listaNegra':
            $_POST['nombres'] = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['nombres'], 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
            $_POST['apellidoP'] = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['apellidoP'], 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
            $_POST['apellidoM'] = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['apellidoM'], 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
            $listaNegra = $personaDB->existsPersonaListaNegra($_POST);
$pct100 = false;
            if(!empty($listaNegra) && is_array($listaNegra)){
                foreach($listaNegra as &$persona){
                    $persona['match'] = '';
                    $porcentaje = 80;
                    if(strtolower($persona['nombres']) == strtolower($_POST['nombres'])){
                        $persona['match'] .= 'name';
                        $porcentaje += 10;
                    }
                    if($_POST['nacimiento'] == $persona['fecha_nacimiento']){
                        $persona['match'] .= 'date';
                        $porcentaje += 10;
                    }
                    $persona['porcentaje'] = $porcentaje;
if($porcentaje == 100)
                        $pct100 = true;
                }
                unset($persona);
            }
    include(ROOT.RUTA_TPL.'ventas/listanegra.tpl.php');
    break;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Specifically the condition I want to pass to jasvascript is variable $pct100

Comment: What code have you already tried? Can you post that as well?

Comment: Do not rely on others to solve your hole issues. Show your code and people will try to help you!

Comment: Please check my question again, I didn't want to post my code because I have some other things not related with the question

Comment: Ok, and now, what is the PHP condition that you should make javascript code know?

Comment: The variable I want to pass to javascript is $pct100, added to my last edit

Comment: You are "directly" outputting HTML code so I think, as a quick workaround, you should write the `$pct100` in a hidden field/dom element and then access it with the `complete callback` in your javascript code. This is an example of what I am suggesting [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKAyC/)

Comment: @user3165879 good idea, why don't you put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are "directly" outputting HTML code so I think, as a quick workaround, you should write the $pct100 in a hidden field/dom element and then access it with the complete callback in your javascript code.

This is an example of what I am suggesting

```
$("#listaNegraView").load(
    'procesos/funcionesAjax.php', 
    {accion: 'listaNegra', 
     nombres: $("#nombres").val(), 
     apellidoP: $("#apellidoP").val(),
     apellidoM: $("#apellidoM").val(),
     nacimiento: $("#nacimiento").val()
    },
    function(data){
        $('#where-to-put-html-code').html(data);
        var pct100 = $('#where-to-put-html-code #hidden-field-id').val() == '1' ? true : false;
    }
);
```

Answer added by the suggestion of the asker.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely will be the easiest solution